# Grabbing stock data from a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm currently working on a very basic program to get stock data and copy it into a .csv file. Not sure If I am using `for x in list` correctly, because I only get one stock's data copied, instead of a separate file for each stock in the list.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
import urllib
import os

enddate = date.today()
startdate = enddate + timedelta(-30) # last 30 days
stocks = ["^RUT", "NFLX", "YHOO", "AAPL", "GOOG"]
for stock in stocks:
    print stock

STOCK_URL = 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv'
PARAMS = {
    'a': startdate.month-1,
    'b': startdate.day,
    'c': startdate.year,
    'd': enddate.month-1,
    'e': enddate.day,
    'f': enddate.year,
    'g': 'd',
    'ignore': '.csv'
}

def pulldata(stock, filename):
    print "Retrieving latest data..."
    params = PARAMS.copy()
    params['s'] = stock
    url = "%s?%s" % (STOCK_URL, urllib.urlencode(params))
    return urllib.urlretrieve(url, filename)
try:
    folder = os.stat("My Stock Data/")
except:
    folder = os.mkdir("My Stock Data/")
filename, headers = pulldata(stock, "My Stock Data/" + stock + "-data.csv")
print "Done"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this exactly how your code looks?

If so, I would expect to see the stock names printed out, and then just the data for GOOG, followed by "Done".

try grabbing the for loop, move it down to just before the call to pulldata, and indent that line so it looks like

```
try:
    folder = os.stat("My Stock Data/")
except:
    folder = os.mkdir("My Stock Data/")

for stock in stocks:
    print(stock)
    filename, headers = pulldata(stock, "My Stock Data/" + stock + "-data.csv")

print("Done")
```